# How to target only the number of this with javascript

Tags: javascript

```
<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
  <bdi>
   <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">RM</span>
   "678"
  </bdi>
</span>
```

How can i target only the number of this bdi without the currency simble with Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update a child node's `textContent`. Depending on the currency, the index will be either 1 or 2. In your case it's 2, because the currency symbol is before the amount.

example:

```js
document.querySelector(".woocommerce-Price-amount bdi").childNodes[2].textContent = '1000';
```

The index 0 is skipped because it is a node with a newline character (thanks @derprischer).

Comment: While `childNodes[].textContent` is the right way to go, your index is wrong. Because the `<bdi>` element has three childnodes. A textnode holding content  `'\n  '`, a `<span>` element and another textnode holding content `'"678"\n  '`. So the correct index for that last nextnode will be `childNodes[2]`